# recover deleted git file, file in github n deletion not staged

Tags: git

So I was working in a pair session and in order to do a large commit I needed to remove some files which were staged. Instead of resetting, which would have removed files I needed to stage, I deleted them. Only afterward did I realize I had deleted a file I shouldn't have. As you can see, the deletion isn't committed. It's not even staged.
There's got to be a way to undo the delete of table-practice...right?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: There is - it's shown in the message from git: "git checkout -- <file>" will discard the change, even when that change is a deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You can undo by giving

`git checkout table-practice.html`

Answer (score 0):

git status

Above should show your files to be deleted.  Run below to recover them.

git reset HEAD <filename(s)>

git checkout <filename(s)